# Changing expression using a new variable definition

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions

If I have an expression that looks like the following:

$$ \frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\sigma _2}{\sigma _1}} \left(-\sigma _2 q_1(t){}^2+\sigma _1 q_2(t){}^2+\left(\omega _2-\omega _1\right) q_2(t) q_1(t)\right)}{q_2(t){}^2}$$

And I'm defining a new variable:

$$ \mathcal{z}\to \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma _2}{\sigma _1}} q_1(t)}{q_2(t)}$$

Is there any way to show the expression using the new defined variable $\mathcal{Z}$?

I tried using replace:

```
% /. ZZ -> Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]]*
  Subscript[q, 1][t]/Subscript[q, 2][t]
```

But the expression stays the same

The input version for the expression is:

```
(I Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]] (-Subscript[\
\[Sigma], 2] Subscript[q, 1][
     t]^2 + (-Subscript[\[Omega], 1] + Subscript[\[Omega], 
      2]) Subscript[q, 1][t] Subscript[q, 2][t] + 
   Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[q, 2][t]^2))/Subscript[q, 2][t]^2
```

Comment: Try q1->q2 z /Sqrt[...]  (with your symbols of course) and then Simplify

Comment: My guess is you can't get better than `I z((1-z^2)q2/q1 \[Sigma]1+(\[Omega]2-\[Omega]1))`.  That is, there is no expression in terms of only z that is equivalent. (I found this by hand, what you're asking is sort of the inverse of `/.`)

Comment: You cannot replace a variable that is not present in the expression, which is what you are attempting to do here. Instead, you must do a process like what Craig Carter indicates, wherein you are replacing a variable that is present in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite expressions in this way using a bare symbol, `Eliminate`, and `Solve`:

```
ClearAll[f];

expr = (I Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]] (-Subscript[\
\[Sigma], 2] Subscript[q, 1][
     t]^2 + (-Subscript[\[Omega], 1] + Subscript[\[Omega], 
      2]) Subscript[q, 1][t] Subscript[q, 2][t] + 
   Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Subscript[q, 2][t]^2))/Subscript[q, 2][t]^2;

zexpr = Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]]*
  Subscript[q, 1][t]/Subscript[q, 2][t];

f /. First@Solve[
            Eliminate[f == expr && ZZ == zexpr, {Subscript[q, 1][t], Subscript[q, 2][t]}],
            f]

(* Out:

-I (-Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/
    Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]] + 
   ZZ^2 Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] Sqrt[Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]/
    Subscript[\[Sigma], 1]] + ZZ Subscript[\[Omega], 1] - 
   ZZ Subscript[\[Omega], 2])

*)
```

(You might want to also apply a `Simplify` to the result, perhaps with second argument (assumption) `Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] > 0`.)

You can also have Mathematica attempt this procedure in general by packaging it in a function `Rewrite`!

```
Rewrite::nosol = "The expression `1` cannot be rewritten in terms of `2`.";
Rewrite::multisol = "The expression `1` cannot be rewritten in terms of `2` in just one way.";
Rewrite::fail = "Something went wrong.";

Rewrite[expr_, z_ == zexpr_, vars_] :=
  Block[{f},
    Replace[{
      {{f -> x_}} :> x,
      {{}}|{_,__} :> (Message[Rewrite::multisol, expr, z]; expr),
      {} :> (Message[Rewrite::nosol, expr, z]; expr),
      _ :> (Message[Rewrite::fail]; expr)
    }] @ Solve[Eliminate[f == expr && z == zexpr, vars], f]
  ]

Rewrite[expr, ZZ == zexpr, {Subscript[q, 1][t], Subscript[q, 2][t]}]
```

At the moment you still have to specify which variables you want to eliminate using the last argument. A more sophisticated version would extract these variables from `zexpr` automatically, or simply do as much rewriting as possible by traversing the expression.